# jquery; how do I show the click-on div and hide all the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm trying to make a webpage where you click on a button to show and hide a div, my problem now is;

How do I hide all of the other div's by clicking on a specific button.

CodeJava:

```
function showHide(divId){
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    if(theDiv.style.display=="none"){
        theDiv.style.display="block";
    }else{
        theDiv.style.display="none";
    }    
}
```

CodeHTML:

```
    <div id="div" onclick="showHide('divcontent')"> This is the button. </div>

    <div id="divcontent"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>



    <div id="div2" onclick="showHide('divcontent2')"> This is the button. </div>

    <div id="divcontent2"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>



    <div id="div3" onclick="showHide('divcontent3')"> This is the button. </div>

    <div id="divcontent3"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>
```

So if you click on div2, I want the others to be displayed hidden.

Comment: Looks like you’re going about this the wrong way. Here’s the functionality I *guess* you’re looking for: [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: this question doesn't need to be downvoted imo

Comment: Accordion would certainly fit the bill, but if he needs some more customization in terms of look and feel then doing independent of the UI library may be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

First, add a way to identify all of your div tags with content (generally done with a class) like so:

```
<div id="div" onclick="showHide('divcontent')"> This is the button. </div>
<div class="content" id="divcontent"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>


<div id="div2" onclick="showHide('divcontent2')"> This is the button. </div>
<div class="content" id="divcontent2"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>


<div id="div3" onclick="showHide('divcontent3')"> This is the button. </div>
<div class="content" id="divcontent3"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>
```

Then, use this function to show/hide content div tags:

```
function showHide(divId){

    $(".contents").not("#" + divId).hide();
    $("#" + divId).show();
}
```

This assumes that somewhere in your page header you've properly included the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do that with CSS Classes

```
<div id="div" class="toclick"> This is the button. </div>
<div id="divcontent" class="tohide"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>

<div id="div2" class="toclick"> This is the button. </div>
<div id="divcontent2" class="tohide"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>

<div id="div3" class="toclick"> This is the button. </div>
<div id="divcontent3" class="tohide"> This is a div to hide and show. </div>
```

With Jquery you can easily access the object you clicked on:

```
$('.toclick').click(function(){
   var doNotDisappear =  $(this).attr('id'); //get id of div
   $('#'+doNotDisappear).next('tohide').removeClass('tohide');
   $('tohide').hide(); //make the other disappear
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible one:

```
function showHide(btn){   
    $(btn).next('.showhide').toggle().siblings('.showhide').hide();
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Kpx/)

Following the relevant HTML:

```
<div onclick="showHide(this)">This is the button.</div>
<div class="showhide">This is a div to hide and show.</div>
<!-- etc... -->
```